# Return JSON object from WCF

Tags: wcf, json

I am working on a wcf.The service will return a serialized JSON object which will include the following structure:

```
{

'status':{'id':0,'code':1},

'data' : object (data object)

}
```

Main problem to make this structure is, how to use object(class object) in this JSON structure.

Please somebody guide me how to pass the "class object" in this JSON structure.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: I believe the `object (data object)` just means that there will be something that is not further specified at this level (but will be specified for particular cases). In any case it can't appear there literally, because it's not valid JSON notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
{    
'status':{'id':0,'code':1},    
'data' : object (data object)    
}
```

'object (data object )' mentioned by you also required to be in valid JSON format. You can provide more information about this object. Tell what you want to save in object. I can provide more details then.
 For Example,

```
{
    "data": {
        "key1": {
            "subKey1": "val1"
        },
        "key2": [
            {
                "subKey1": "subVal1",
                "subKey2": "subVal2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You should always use [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate the json structure.